# Cryptic Family Reunion #7

Tags: cryptic-clues

The answer to this puzzle is a list of ten thematically related words or proper names or phrases. Each of these is clued cryptically, and the theme is to be determined. Since the definition part of a cryptic clue would give away the theme, these cryptic clues use a family member (e.g., mom, sister) to stand in for the definition part of the clue. So for example, if the theme of the puzzle were chemical elements, "Sister picking at nit" would clue "tin". Clues are sorted with answers in **alphabetical order**, and lengths of each answer are given with the clues.

1. Nephew flips after PR man blows a grand (4)
2. Reportedly *Runaway* singer played with Grandpa (7)
3. It's too much to expect unusual scheme originates with grandma (7)
4. Daughter makes silly faces putting on hat and jewelry (9)
5. Uncle sees most of Latin America, picks up a girl (10)
6. Dad races pilot in flight (10)
7. Son has intermittent spasm of abs (5)
8. Lawn at Texas university an afterthought to niece (10)
9. Son-in-law seems to measure up, loading gun, discarding shell after shooting clays (9)
10. Brother wrote buggy script that handles only one exception (7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The theme is:

> **muscles of the body**

Explanation:

> 1. (flack - K)< -- calf
>  2. "Del (shannon) toyed" -- deltoid
>  3. glut + e_ u_ s_ -- gluteus
>  4. hat containing m(akes) s(illy) + ring -- hamstring
>  5. LATIn + miss< + US -- latissimus
>  6. racespilot*  -- pectoralis
>  7. 'spasm of abs' alternating letters -- psoas
>  8. "quad (at) rice" + PS -- quadriceps
>  9. trap + size< containing gUn -- trapezius
>  10. script* contain e(xception) -- triceps

Comment: Thanks for catching the error on #10. I have fixed it. Good thing I spent all those years studying math. One more to go!

Comment: Perfectly correct! Great job!